# While List isn't empty, remove a random element from List results in infinite loop

Tags: c#, list, loops, generics, shuffle

I am working on a simple *shuffle script*. I have a Generic method which takes as input a `List<T>` and returns a `List<T>`. The returned `List` should be *shuffled*. However, the code got stuck in an **infinite loop**, and I'm not sure **why**.

Here is my code:

```
private List<T> Shuffle<T>(List<T> p)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    int idx = 0;

    while (p.Count > 0)
    {
        idx = Random.Range(0, p.Count);

        print(idx);
        result.Add(p[idx]);
        p.Remove(p[idx]);
    }

    print("Shuffled");
    return result;
}
```

I would expect the code to work, since `p.Count` *keeps getting smaller*. However, it **gets stuck**. Here is an alternative to the `while` loop I made which works, but feels somewhat sloppy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < p.Count; i++)
{
    idx = Random.Range(0, p.Count);
    print(idx);

    result.Add(p[idx]);
    p.Remove(p[idx]);
}
```

This is more of a **"why"** question than a problem, but I still hope you may be able to help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `List<T> result = p;` is the problem: you remove and insert into *itself*. Should be `List<T> result = new List<T>();`

Comment: Step thru your code... breakpoint anywhere in your while loop.  Add a watch to "result" and "p".  You'll see they're the same.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko wow... Thanks, that is horrendous. However, no reason for it to go infinite, right?

Comment: Voting to close, as the question has been edited so the problem is no longer reproducable.   Also question will never be found  by someone else with same misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first line

```
List<T> result = p;
```

is the *problem*. Note, that `result` and `p` share the *same reference*, that's why

```
result.Add(p[idx]);
```

adds to `result` and to `p` **as well**, `p.Count > 0` **ever holds** (turning `while (p.Count > 0)` into *infinite loop*). Should be

```
private List<T> Shuffle<T>(List<T> p)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>(); // result and p are different lists now

    while (p.Count > 0)
    {
        idx = Random.Range(0, p.Count);

        print(idx);
        result.Add(p[idx]);  // Now we Add to result only, and Remove from p
        p.RemoveAt(idx);     // <- I suggest removing at index
    }

    print("Shuffled");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tested, it works! I'll accept your answer when able. Thanks a lot!